# Torch for camera "0" is not available due to an existing camera user Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to turn on the flash-light/ torch while the camera is on in my flutter application. I'm using the [torchcompat](https://pub.dev/packages/torch_compat) flutter package, I've used really all the flutter packages about torch but all of them give me the same two errors :

1. android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_IN_USE (4): setTorchMode:1598: Torch for camera "0" is not available due to an existing camera user
2. Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method turnOn on channel g123k/torch_compat)

My Manifest.xml :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

I've done a lot of search and all of solutions telling me to run flutter clean and flutter run.

Comment: Try camerakit (https://pub.dev/packages/camerakit) for flash. Might it help you.

Answer (score 0):

setTorchMode

Added in API level 23

public void setTorchMode (String cameraId,
boolean enabled)
Set the flash unit's torch mode of the camera of the given ID without opening the camera device.

Use getCameraIdList() to get the list of available camera devices and use getCameraCharacteristics(String) to check whether the camera device has a flash unit. Note that even if a camera device has a flash unit, turning on the torch mode may fail if the camera device or other camera resources needed to turn on the torch mode are in use.

If setTorchMode(String, boolean) is called to turn on or off the torch mode successfully, CameraManager.TorchCallback#onTorchModeChanged will be invoked. However, even if turning on the torch mode is successful, the application does not have the exclusive ownership of the flash unit or the camera device. The torch mode will be turned off and becomes unavailable when the camera device that the flash unit belongs to becomes unavailable or when other camera resources to keep the torch on become unavailable ( CameraManager.TorchCallback#onTorchModeUnavailable will be invoked). Also, other applications are free to call setTorchMode(String, boolean) to turn off the torch mode ( CameraManager.TorchCallback#onTorchModeChanged will be invoked). If the latest application that turned on the torch mode exits, the torch mode will be turned off.